# Creating a VF that redirects to another URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

I am trying to create a VF page, which I want on the Home Page.  When certain profiles login, I want them to be redirected to another URL (let's use www.google.com as an example).

I am trying to create a Controller & VF page using some resources online.  For my controller I am using the following:

Apex Method:

```
    public PageReference doRedirectAction(){

      //Write your logic here and redirect
      PageReference retURL = new PageReference('www.google.com');
      retURL.setRedirect(true);
      return retURL;

 }
```

But I am getting an error - Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'PageReference' at line 1 column 8

What would I need to do to overcome it?

Controller:

```
public class myCtrl{

    public myCtrl()
    {

    }

    public PageReference pageReferenceMethod()
    {
          return new PageReference('/001');
     }

}
```

Comment: when you click on the link, what do your browser dev tools tell you?

Comment: Is that your entire controller so far? If so, you have a syntax problem. What you have here looks like a _method_ rather than a _controller or extension_

Comment: Sorry Derek, it is an APEX Method.

Comment: Please post the entire content of your `Apex Class`.

Comment: glls - This is my first time trying VF page, so clearly I wasn't 100% sure what I was doing -.-".
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further details in your post,

a simple VF page which invokes the method on page load:

```
<apex:page controller="pagedirections" action="{!urlRedirection}">
</apex:page>
```

and a controller:

```
public class pagedirections {

    public PageReference urlRedirection() {

          string url = 'http://www.google.ca/';

          PageReference page = new PageReference(url);
          page.setRedirect(true);
          return page;
    }
}
```

works perfectly fine.

You might want to provide minimal code samples of what you are attempting to do and how  in order to get more accurate answers.

if you go to the Apex PageReference Class [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm), you can get further details on the methods.

are you redirecting those users  to an external site or within your org? more details would be appreciated. As is, we are kind of limited as what we can provide as answers...

Comment: Will do! Thank you, 1 Question I do have is there a way to have it redirect the same tab this page is opened on rather than opening a brand new Tab?

Comment: hehe, if you search the forum, i'm pretty sure you will find the answer. if you dont find it, open a new question (this is basic javascript =P )

Comment: quick hint - look for target attribute of whatever apex/html tag you are using to achieve this

Comment: This works for redirecting to a `mailto` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of method name it is giving error

```
public class MyController
{
    public PageReference doRedirectAction(){

      //Write your logic here and redirect
      PageReference retURL = new PageReference('www.google.com');
      retURL.setRedirect(true);
      return retURL;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Santanu, but I am still getting the same error..

Comment: can you update your apex class and component at your question

Comment: I just copied and used what you written.  So far I am just working on the Apex Method, I still have to figure out what the controller would look like.

Comment: apex method must belong to a controller